# Issue with condition If with Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send to server with ajax two kind of information with two button inside a form, like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return post2();">
 <div>
   <input type="submit" id="green" value="1">
   <input type="submit" id="red" value="3">
 </div>
</form>
```

Ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function post2() {
          var green = document.getElementById('green').value;
          var red = document.getElementById('red').value;
      if (green || red) {
            $.ajax ({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'server_action.php',
              data: {
                user_green:green,
                user_red:red
              }
            });
        }
          return false;
      }
</script>
```

But it fire once. Information sent is only green or only red, then it stop working. I would like to avoid creating two forms with two functions in ajax. Is possible switch from green to red and viceversa with the same form and function?

Comment: you need to submit both values  at onces ?

Comment: @Swati no, I want to submit only the value I choose

Comment: instead of `<input type="submit">` use `<input type="button">` and to get required value use `click` event of jquery .